# Upading value in dictionary within class in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

How do I update a value in a dictionary within a class?

The function 'read_messages' should print the first N messages in the user's inbox that has been created in `__init__` and change their 'read' value to `True` so that they will not be printed them next time the function is called.

Here is my code:

```
class Outlook:
    def __init__(self, users):
        self.message_id = 0
        self.inboxes = {usr: [] for usr in users}

    def send_email(self, sender, recipient, title, body):
        user_inbox = self.inboxes[recipient]
        self.message_id = self.message_id + 1
        message_details = {
            'id': self.message_id,
            'title': title,
            'body': body,
            'sender': sender,
            'read': False
        }
        user_inbox.append(message_details)
        return self.message_id

    def read_messages(self, user, N):
        user_inbox = self.inboxes[user]
        for message in user_inbox[:N]:
            if message['read'] == False:
                print(message)
                message['read'] = True # this does not seem to work


ol1 = Outlook(['James Bond'])

ol1.send_email(
    sender='M',
    recipient='James Bond',
    title='Return to England!',
    body='James, return to England immediately',
)
ol1.send_email(
    sender='Miss Moneypenny',
    recipient='James Bond',
    title='Meeting with M',
    body='James, M wants to see you tomorrow at 11:00',
)

ol1.read_messages('James Bond',2)
```

EDIT: after the first call of 'ol1.read_messages' I expect no items to be printed when it is called again.

Comment: Works for me. Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: @finswimmer the two messages are printed everytime `ol1.read_messages` is called.

Comment: Hm, not here :( But another question: What is `N` for in `read_messages`. Do you expect to print `N` unread messages? This would not be the case in the moment, as you will iterate only over the first `N` messages, regardless whether they are unread or not.

Comment: Yes, the first N unread messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works my friend! I think that your issue is one of persistency. If you call `ol1.read_messages('James Bond',2)` consecutively (i.e. write the instruction twice), you'll see that the messages are only printed once. The second call does not print any items. However, running the python program consecutively will display these messages every time because every time the program is ran, the messages are created again.

I modified your code slightly so that you can see this in effect. Here, I have it print the messages regardless of whether they have been read. You can see that the second time the messages are printrf, the `read` attribute has been set to `false`. This means you are correctly updating the dictionary.

However, you will see the 2 messages printed every time you run the code because each time you run your program, you are starting from scratch. At the end of the program, the memory that `ol1` is stored in is returned to the system, and when the program is started again, `ol1` is recreated and new messages are given to it.

```
class Outlook:
    def __init__(self, users):
        self.message_id = 0
        self.inboxes = {usr: [] for usr in users}

    def send_email(self, sender, recipient, title, body):
        user_inbox = self.inboxes[recipient]
        self.message_id = self.message_id + 1
        message_details = {
            'id': self.message_id,
            'title': title,
            'body': body,
            'sender': sender,
            'read': False
        }
        user_inbox.append(message_details)
        return self.message_id

    def read_messages(self, user, N):
        user_inbox = self.inboxes[user]
        for message in user_inbox[:N]:
            if message['read'] == False:
                print(message)
                message['read'] = True 
            else: # This will print read messages
                print(message)


ol1 = Outlook(['James Bond'])

ol1.send_email(
    sender='M',
    recipient='James Bond',
    title='Return to England!',
    body='James, return to England immediately',
)

ol1.send_email(
    sender='Miss Moneypenny',
    recipient='James Bond',
    title='Meeting with M',
    body='James, M wants to see you tomorrow at 11:00',
)

ol1.read_messages('James Bond', 2)

print('\nThis time the "read" attribute is true')
ol1.read_messages('James Bond', 2)
```